# Using strings.xml in raw xml resource

Tags: android, xml, string, localization, android-resources

I was wondering if it's possible to load resources from strings.xml in raw xml resource. Example:

```
<root>
<element>@string/res1</element>
<element>@string/res2</element>
<element>@string/res3</element>
</root>
```

Is this possible?

If it's not possible, if I create a raw xml resource, do I have to provide multiple files for localization purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to use values declared in `strings.xml` in a file inside `/raw/`? Then no, that's not possible. If you want to internationalize your "raw" XMLs you can provide one for each of your supported languages in the appropriate folder (`/raw-fr/`, `/raw-en/`, etc). At least that's out of the box.

Alternatively, you can establish a template format and parse the raw XMLs in Java and fetch the appropriate string resource from there instead.

Comment: Can you give an example of the second suggestion?

Comment: `<element attribute="{!myString!}">{!myString2!}</element>` You'd read the XML then replace all instances of {!*!} with the appropriate string from your resources.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any tutorial or example where I can read up on this?

Comment: I'm sure there are some tutorials floating around on general templating, but this seems a bit specific (and non-standard) for android...